# How to Enable dynamic textbox onclick using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have textboxes created with DB fields and a "E" for Edit link next to it. Initially the text fields are disabled. If the user wants to modify the value from DB they would click the link and the textbox next to it will be enable. The problem is that it is modifying the first text box of the same code number. This is probably because the id attribute on text field is the same and I would like to properly identified text but have failed.
Here is my code

```
<input type="text" name="form_line[code]" size="10"
    value='<?php echo bucks($tmp['adj_amount']); ?>' disabled="true" id="editable"/>

<a id="myedit" title="Click to Edit Adjustment Value" href="#" onclick="edit_adj();return false;">E</a>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function edit_adj() {
        document.getElementById("editable").disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

An example of output is shown below and if I click on "E" the first textbox gets enabled :(
[image]

Comment: Am I reading your question right that your page has duplicate ids?  Duplicate ids in an HTML page is not supported.  Each id should be unique.

Comment: But I have read that you cannot put id=id[x] so as it is created dynamically I do not know what to replace it with.

Comment: you already disabled it then how are you going to click it?

Comment: Onload they are disabled, but user should be able to click "E" and the correct textbox should be enable to modify value

Comment: It sounds to me like the php code that generates these edit fields is outputting in a loop or somehow creating more than 1 edit field.  If this is true, I can suggest an answer for you.

Comment: More are less - it is actually displaying all charges per customer -every line is a different charge. That is the reason there will be more than one edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
<?php
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++) {
?>
<input type="text" name="somename" size="10"
    value='<?php echo "hello" ?>' disabled="true" id="editable<?php echo $x ?>"/>

<a id="myedit" title="Click to Edit Adjustment Value" href="#" onclick="edit_adj(<?php   echo $x ?>);return false;">Edit</a>
<br/>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit_adj(id) {
    document.getElementById("editable"+id).disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps!
Essentially, this is giving a unique id to each text field and passing the id into the javascript that enables the text field in question.  I created a test page locally and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much this did it!!! I didn't know you could do it like this and is very clever :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Would you mind accepting it as the answer?  :-)